# How can i get subscribe to only last data?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, event-bus

i am doing system of searching in my App. And i subscribe on EventBusEvent

```
addSubscription(TheApplication.getEventBus().observe(UpdateSearchResults.class).subscribe(event ->
        getViewModel().setParameter(event.getText())
    ));
```

Event:

```
public class UpdateSearchResults
{
    public UpdateSearchResults(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

    private String text;
}
```

And each time when user input new symbol. I send event like this:

```
TheApplication.getEventBus().post(new UpdateSearchResults(newText));
```

Can i with help rxJava handle only  last data?

Example: user is input string fast: "Example" and after input symbol **"e"** subscription will work. But for other symbols subscription will not work.

What kind of solutions to the problem exist?

Comment: @tynn i ain't know. maybe there is some RX function in which you send time period and when period is over in subscriber falls into last sended event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method [`debounce()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#debounce(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) which can be used to delay an emission of an item until a timeout occurred after the original event.

This means: as long as the user types, new events will be emitted and thus the old ones being dropped. When the user stops typing, the timeout will be reached and the last event emitted to the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

I create class who send new data once per set period.

```
public class EventSendOnPeriod
{
    public EventSendOnPeriod(Long period)
    {
        this.period = period;
        this.isChange = false;

        handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (isChange)
                    {
                        TheApplication.getEventBus().post(new UpdateSearchResults(text));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, period);
                    isChange = false;
                }
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
    }

    public void sendEvent(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
        isChange = true;
    }

    private final Long period;
    private String text;
    private Boolean isChange;
    private final Handler handler;
}
```

It's very easy for use. You should just use:

```
eventSendOnPeriod.sendEvent(newText);
```

The class yourself once time per period send new data.

**Variant #2:**

```
addSubscription(TheApplication.getEventBus().observe(UpdateSearchResults.class).debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(event ->
        getViewModel().setParameter(event.getText())
    ));
```